# Ajax unable to submit form and call PHP code

Tags: php, ajax

i had met some difficulty on solving my ajax call on the php code. 
I was able to call the bannerDeleteItem.php when i hardcode the code with action ="bannerDeleteItem.php", but when i trying to use ajax call to go to bannerDeleteItem.php, it just refresh the page only. Is there any mistake that i had made in my code? Please correct me if i'm wrong because i still new to the ajax function. Thanks

Here is my banner.php code:

```
<tbody>

                                        <?php

                                            include 'dbConnect.php';
                                            global $conn;

                                            $query = "SELECT * FROM I_Banner WHERE banner_kiosk ='1' ";
                                            $result = sqlsrv_query($conn,$query);

                                            while( $row = sqlsrv_fetch_array ( $result, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC )){
                                        ?>
                                        <tr>
                                                    <td><?php echo $row['banner_name']; ?></td>
                                                    <td><?php echo $row['banner_description']; ?></td>
                                                <form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                                                    <input type="hidden" name="banner_id" value="<?php echo $row['banner_id']?>"> 
                                                    <td><center/><button id="delete" class="btn btn-info btn-sm" title="Remove"><i class="fa fa-times"></td>
                                                </form>
                                        </tr>
                                        <?php
                                            }
                                            sqlsrv_free_stmt($result);
                                            sqlsrv_close($conn);
                                        ?>


                                        </tbody>
....
$(document).ready(function(){
                //Delete banner item confirm box
                $("button#delete").confirm({

                     confirm: function (el) {
                        $.ajax({
                            url: 'bannerDeleteItem.php',
                            data: el.closest('form').serialize(),
                            type: 'post',
                        }).done(function () {
                            //do something if you want when the post is successfully
                            if(!alert('Form Had Successfully Deleted.')){location.reload(); }
                        }).fail(function () {
                            //if the post is failed show an error message if you want
                            alert('Some error occur. Please try again later.');
                        }).always(function () {
                            //this is executed on success and failure
                            $('#myhiddendiv').hide();
                        })  
                    }
                });
```

Here is my bannerDeleteItem.php :

```
<?php
include 'dbConnect.php';

global $conn;


    //Gather all required data
    $item_id = $_POST['banner_id'];

    //Delete file directory function
    $query = "SELECT banner_data FROM I_Banner WHERE banner_id='$item_id'";
    $result = sqlsrv_query($conn,$query);

    while($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array ( $result, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC )){
        //Create the SQL query
        $delete = "DELETE FROM I_Banner WHERE banner_id = '$item_id' ";
        //Execute the query
        $deleteResult = sqlsrv_query($conn,$delete);
        $data = "uploads/$row[banner_data]";
        unlink($data);

    }

    // Close the mysql connection
    sqlsrv_close($conn);


// Echo a link back to the main page
echo '<p>Click <a href="index.html">here</a> to go back</p>';
?>
```

The bannerDeleleItem.php code is working, just that when i'm press the "delete" button , it pop out the confirmation box and i click Okay but nothing happen. It seem like my ajax code does not proceed to the bannerDeleteItem.php code. Any place that i had make mistake on? Please correct me

Answer (score 0):

I had solve this with replacing my form inside the

It something look like this:

```
<td>
    <form class="form" id="form" action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
       <input type="hidden" name="banner_id" value="<?php echo $row['banner_id']?>"></input>
       <center/><button id="delete" class="btn btn-info btn-sm" title="Remove"><i class="fa fa-times"></i>
    </form>
</td>
```

I had mistakenly replace the form outside the table data which the data should be submit within the table data.